# Determine GARCH(1,1) from a mean reverting time series recursion

Tags: time-series, garch, variance, heston

Let $(v_t)$ be a discrete time series of variance obeying a mean-reverting variance process $v_t$, which is actually the discrete version of the Heston model in finance.
\begin{align}
x_t &= \sqrt{v_t} z_{1,t} \tag1\\
v_{t}-v_{t-1} &= -\lambda(v_{t-1}-v_\infty)+\eta\sqrt[]{v_{t-1}}z_{2,t-1}  \tag2
\end{align}
where $z_{1,t}$ and $z_{2,t}$ is two not necessarily independent unit variance random walks with correlation and $\eta$ is some positive constant.

I would like to make an approximate GARCH(1,1) model for the variance out of the above time series in the form of 
$$v_t = \alpha_0+\alpha x_{t-1}^2+\beta v_{t-1}$$
where $\alpha_0,\,\alpha,\,\beta$ are positive and $\alpha+\beta<1$.

Here is my rough ad hoc attempt. Take expectation of Equation (2) and arrange the terms we have
$$u_t = \lambda u_\infty+(1-\lambda)u_{t-1}$$
where $u_t:=\mathbf E[v_t]$. Now set
$$\tilde u_t = \lambda \tilde u_\infty+(1-\lambda)(ax_{t-1}^2+b\tilde u_{t-1})$$
for some positive $a$ and $b$ where $a+b=1$. Now $\alpha_0 = \lambda u_\infty,\,\alpha=(1-\lambda)a,\,\beta=(1-\lambda)b$. How would one determine $a,\,b$ from the time series recursion Equation (1) and (2)?